# High CPU since upgrading to MySQL 5.7 from 5.6

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql5.6, mysql5.7

We are using an AWS RDS managed MySQL db.m4.2xlarge instance with db engine 5.7.30, we upgraded from 5.6 two days ago and have high CPU since - generally 10-15% higher reaching 100% at peek. Please can you help us understand the reason for this? N.B. noticeable drop in load over weekend expected.

[CPU load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0ds3.png)

The highest SQL load by waits are admin queries so this does not seem to be down to a badly optimised SQL:

[Top SQL load by waits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3oGq.png)

We are using mysql-connector-java 8.0.21 to connect to the database and heavily use connection pooling, could this be a reason for this high usage selecting transaction isolation? N.B. this usage was high, but not as high, before the upgrade.

### show global variables;

```
Variable_name,Value
auto_generate_certs,ON
auto_increment_increment,1
auto_increment_offset,1
autocommit,ON
automatic_sp_privileges,ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade,OFF
back_log,582
basedir,/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.30.R4/
big_tables,OFF
bind_address,*
binlog_cache_size,32768
binlog_checksum,CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates,OFF
binlog_error_action,ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format,MIXED
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay,0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count,0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery,ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time,0
binlog_order_commits,ON
binlog_row_image,FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events,OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size,32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size,25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking,COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode,aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size,8388608
character_set_client,latin1
character_set_connection,latin1
character_set_database,latin1
character_set_filesystem,binary
character_set_results,latin1
character_set_server,latin1
character_set_system,utf8
character_sets_dir,/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.30.R4/share/charsets/
check_proxy_users,OFF
collation_connection,latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database,latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server,latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type,NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert,AUTO
connect_timeout,10
core_file,OFF
datadir,/rdsdbdata/db/
date_format,%Y-%m-%d
datetime_format,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"
default_authentication_plugin,mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime,0
default_storage_engine,InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine,InnoDB
default_week_format,0
delay_key_write,ON
delayed_insert_limit,100
delayed_insert_timeout,300
delayed_queue_size,1000
disabled_storage_engines,
disconnect_on_expired_password,ON
div_precision_increment,4
end_markers_in_json,OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency,OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit,200
event_scheduler,OFF
expire_logs_days,0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp,ON
flush,OFF
flush_time,0
foreign_key_checks,ON
ft_boolean_syntax,"+ -><()~*:""""&|"
ft_max_word_len,84
ft_min_word_len,4
ft_query_expansion_limit,20
ft_stopword_file,(built-in)
general_log,OFF
general_log_file,/rdsdbdata/log/general/mysql-general.log
group_concat_max_len,1024
gtid_executed,
gtid_executed_compression_period,1000
gtid_mode,OFF_PERMISSIVE
gtid_owned,
gtid_purged,
have_compress,YES
have_crypt,YES
have_dynamic_loading,YES
have_geometry,YES
have_openssl,YES
have_profiling,YES
have_query_cache,YES
have_rtree_keys,YES
have_ssl,YES
have_statement_timeout,YES
have_symlink,YES
host_cache_size,736
hostname,ip-172-20-1-56
ignore_builtin_innodb,OFF
ignore_db_dirs,
init_connect,
init_file,
init_slave,
innodb_adaptive_flushing,ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm,10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index,ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts,8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay,150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval,5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock,OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog,OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl,OFF
innodb_api_trx_level,0
innodb_autoextend_increment,64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode,1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size,134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown,ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now,OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct,25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename,ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances,8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort,OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup,ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now,OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size,24696061952
innodb_change_buffer_max_size,25
innodb_change_buffering,all
innodb_checksum_algorithm,crc32
innodb_checksums,ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled,OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency,0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct,5
innodb_compression_level,6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max,50
innodb_concurrency_tickets,5000
innodb_data_file_path,ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir,/rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_deadlock_detect,ON
innodb_default_row_format,dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache,OFF
innodb_doublewrite,ON
innodb_fast_shutdown,1
innodb_file_format,Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check,ON
innodb_file_format_max,Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table,ON
innodb_fill_factor,100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout,1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit,1
innodb_flush_method,O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors,1
innodb_flush_sync,ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops,30
innodb_force_load_corrupted,OFF
innodb_force_recovery,0
innodb_ft_aux_table,
innodb_ft_cache_size,8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print,OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword,ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size,84
innodb_ft_min_token_size,3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize,2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit,2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table,
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree,2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size,640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table,
innodb_io_capacity,200
innodb_io_capacity_max,2000
innodb_large_prefix,ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout,60
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog,OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size,8388608
innodb_log_checksums,ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages,ON
innodb_log_file_size,134217728
innodb_log_files_in_group,2
innodb_log_group_home_dir,/rdsdbdata/log/innodb
innodb_log_write_ahead_size,8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth,1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct,75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm,0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag,0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay,0
innodb_max_undo_log_size,1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable,
innodb_monitor_enable,
innodb_monitor_reset,
innodb_monitor_reset_all,
innodb_numa_interleave,OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct,37
innodb_old_blocks_time,1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size,134217728
innodb_open_files,2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only,OFF
innodb_page_cleaners,4
innodb_page_size,16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks,OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size,300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency,128
innodb_purge_threads,1
innodb_random_read_ahead,OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold,56
innodb_read_io_threads,16
innodb_read_only,OFF
innodb_replication_delay,0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout,OFF
innodb_rollback_segments,128
innodb_sort_buffer_size,1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay,6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc,ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked,OFF
innodb_stats_method,nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata,OFF
innodb_stats_persistent,ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages,20
innodb_stats_sample_pages,8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages,8
innodb_status_output,OFF
innodb_status_output_locks,OFF
innodb_strict_mode,ON
innodb_support_xa,ON
innodb_sync_array_size,1
innodb_sync_spin_loops,30
innodb_table_locks,ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path,ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency,0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay,10000
innodb_tmpdir,
innodb_undo_directory,./
innodb_undo_log_truncate,OFF
innodb_undo_logs,128
innodb_undo_tablespaces,0
innodb_use_native_aio,ON
innodb_version,5.7.30
innodb_write_io_threads,16
interactive_timeout,28800
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine,InnoDB
join_buffer_size,262144
keep_files_on_create,OFF
key_buffer_size,16777216
key_cache_age_threshold,300
key_cache_block_size,1024
key_cache_division_limit,100
keyring_operations,ON
large_files_support,ON
large_page_size,0
large_pages,OFF
lc_messages,en_US
lc_messages_dir,/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.30.R4/share/
lc_time_names,en_US
license,GPL
local_infile,ON
lock_wait_timeout,31536000
locked_in_memory,OFF
log_bin,ON
log_bin_basename,/rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
log_bin_index,/rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators,OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events,OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password,OFF
log_error,/rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
log_error_verbosity,3
log_output,FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes,OFF
log_slave_updates,ON
log_slow_admin_statements,OFF
log_slow_slave_statements,OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog,OFF
log_syslog,OFF
log_syslog_facility,daemon
log_syslog_include_pid,ON
log_syslog_tag,
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes,0
log_timestamps,UTC
log_warnings,2
long_query_time,2.000000
low_priority_updates,OFF
lower_case_file_system,OFF
lower_case_table_names,0
master_info_repository,TABLE
master_verify_checksum,OFF
max_allowed_packet,4194304
max_binlog_cache_size,18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size,134217728
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size,18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors,100
max_connections,2664
max_delayed_threads,20
max_digest_length,1024
max_error_count,64
max_execution_time,0
max_heap_table_size,16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads,20
max_join_size,18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data,1024
max_points_in_geometry,65536
max_prepared_stmt_count,16382
max_relay_log_size,0
max_seeks_for_key,18446744073709551615
max_sort_length,1024
max_sp_recursion_depth,0
max_tmp_tables,32
max_user_connections,0
max_write_lock_count,18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size,1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances,8
min_examined_row_limit,0
multi_range_count,256
myisam_data_pointer_size,6
myisam_max_sort_file_size,9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size,18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options,OFF
myisam_repair_threads,1
myisam_sort_buffer_size,8388608
myisam_stats_method,nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap,OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users,OFF
net_buffer_length,16384
net_read_timeout,30
net_retry_count,10
net_write_timeout,60
new,OFF
ngram_token_size,2
offline_mode,OFF
old,OFF
old_alter_table,OFF
old_passwords,0
open_files_limit,65535
optimizer_prune_level,1
optimizer_search_depth,62
optimizer_switch,"index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on"
optimizer_trace,"enabled=off,one_line=off"
optimizer_trace_features,"greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on"
optimizer_trace_limit,1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size,16384
optimizer_trace_offset,-1
parser_max_mem_size,18446744073709551615
performance_schema,ON
performance_schema_accounts_size,-1
performance_schema_digests_size,10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size,10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size,10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size,10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size,10
performance_schema_hosts_size,-1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes,80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_digest_length,1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes,80
performance_schema_max_file_handles,32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_index_stat,-1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes,320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks,-1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes,210
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_program_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes,50
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes,10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length,1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes,150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes,193
performance_schema_max_statement_stack,10
performance_schema_max_table_handles,-1
performance_schema_max_table_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat,-1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes,50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances,-1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size,512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size,-1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size,-1
performance_schema_users_size,-1
pid_file,/rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
plugin_dir,/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.30.R4/lib/plugin/
port,3306
preload_buffer_size,32768
profiling,OFF
profiling_history_size,15
protocol_version,10
query_alloc_block_size,8192
query_cache_limit,1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit,4096
query_cache_size,1048576
query_cache_type,OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate,OFF
query_prealloc_size,8192
range_alloc_block_size,4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size,8388608
rbr_exec_mode,STRICT
read_buffer_size,262144
read_only,OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size,524288
relay_log,/rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
relay_log_basename,/rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
relay_log_index,/rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog.index
relay_log_info_file,relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository,TABLE
relay_log_purge,ON
relay_log_recovery,ON
relay_log_space_limit,0
report_host,
report_password,
report_port,3306
report_user,
require_secure_transport,OFF
rpl_stop_slave_timeout,31536000
secure_auth,ON
secure_file_priv,/tmp/
server_id,1956542754
server_id_bits,32
server_uuid,d6028976-235e-11e5-b42b-06e7b18016ef
session_track_gtids,OFF
session_track_schema,ON
session_track_state_change,OFF
session_track_system_variables,"time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection"
session_track_transaction_info,OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys,ON
sha256_password_private_key_path,private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users,OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path,public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56,OFF
show_create_table_verbosity,OFF
show_old_temporals,OFF
skip_external_locking,ON
skip_name_resolve,OFF
skip_networking,OFF
skip_show_database,OFF
slave_allow_batching,OFF
slave_checkpoint_group,512
slave_checkpoint_period,300
slave_compressed_protocol,OFF
slave_exec_mode,STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir,/rdsdbdata/tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet,1073741824
slave_net_timeout,60
slave_parallel_type,DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers,0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max,16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order,OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms,"TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN"
slave_skip_errors,OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum,ON
slave_transaction_retries,10
slave_type_conversions,
slow_launch_time,2
slow_query_log,ON
slow_query_log_file,/rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
socket,/tmp/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size,262144
sql_auto_is_null,OFF
sql_big_selects,ON
sql_buffer_result,OFF
sql_log_off,OFF
sql_mode,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes,ON
sql_quote_show_create,ON
sql_safe_updates,OFF
sql_select_limit,18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter,0
sql_warnings,OFF
ssl_ca,/rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/ca-cert.pem
ssl_capath,
ssl_cert,/rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
ssl_crl,
ssl_crlpath,
ssl_key,/rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-key.pem
stored_program_cache,256
super_read_only,OFF
sync_binlog,1
sync_frm,ON
sync_master_info,10000
sync_relay_log,10000
sync_relay_log_info,10000
system_time_zone,UTC
table_definition_cache,1400
table_open_cache,2000
table_open_cache_instances,16
thread_cache_size,34
thread_handling,one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack,262144
time_format,%H:%i:%s
time_zone,UTC
tls_version,"TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
tmp_table_size,16777216
tmpdir,/rdsdbdata/tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size,8192
transaction_isolation,REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size,4096
transaction_read_only,OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction,OFF
tx_isolation,REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only,OFF
unique_checks,ON
updatable_views_with_limit,YES
version,5.7.30-log
version_comment,"Source distribution"
version_compile_machine,x86_64
version_compile_os,Linux
wait_timeout,28800
```

### show engine innodb status;

```
=====================================
2020-08-18 09:42:51 0x2b36bdbd2700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 13 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 132840 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 0 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 132840
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2787012
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 4423847
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 3451671, OS waits 1515509
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 15355052, OS waits 769142
RW-sx spins 40, rounds 1133, OS waits 29
Spin rounds per wait: 3451671.00 RW-shared, 15355052.00 RW-excl, 28.32 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1676647012889
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1676647012145 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 372
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 328987083690264, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
... // removed duplicates
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 46495720, OS thread handle 47519970961152, query id 3567051327 10.0.198.107 ebx_rw_01_20
---TRANSACTION 1676647012884, ACTIVE 0 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 46497807, OS thread handle 47524538291968, query id 3567050794 10.0.198.107 ebx_rw_01_20
---TRANSACTION 1676647012170, ACTIVE 4 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 46464623, OS thread handle 47518251296512, query id 3566891898 10.0.1.122 ebx_rw_01_20
---TRANSACTION 1676645913638, ACTIVE 9742 sec
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 42190865, OS thread handle 47515543873280, query id 3232481962 10.0.1.206 ebx_rw_01_20
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 10 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 11 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 12 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 13 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 14 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 15 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 16 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 17 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 18 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 19 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 20 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 21 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 22 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 23 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 24 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 25 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 26 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 27 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 28 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 29 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 30 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 31 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 32 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 33 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
687373 OS file reads, 8513991 OS file writes, 7520346 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 102.45 writes/s, 74.53 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 1651, seg size 1653, 1640 merges
merged operations:
 insert 1489, delete mark 517, delete 57
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 184 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 26 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 66 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 1024 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 106216 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6109417, node heap has 96 buffer(s)
256757.10 hash searches/s, 105104.61 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 6938569382427
Log flushed up to   6938569381970
Pages flushed up to 6938548838835
Last checkpoint at  6938548838835
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
7353142 log i/o's done, 71.85 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 25286934528
Dictionary memory allocated 352151
Buffer pool size   1507328
Free buffers       705050
Database pages     694660
Old database pages 256575
Modified db pages  3429
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 583, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 687319, created 7341, written 1099921
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 694660, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       87397
Database pages     87591
Old database pages 32352
Modified db pages  390
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 68, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 86622, created 969, written 126056
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 87591, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       87740
Database pages     87240
Old database pages 32223
Modified db pages  530
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 84, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 86249, created 991, written 132509
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 87240, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       88994
Database pages     85951
Old database pages 31745
Modified db pages  423
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 63, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 85296, created 655, written 130995
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 85951, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       86936
Database pages     88039
Old database pages 32518
Modified db pages  605
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 81, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 86882, created 1157, written 149541
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 88039, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       89757
Database pages     85188
Old database pages 31465
Modified db pages  509
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 74, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 84178, created 1010, written 169407
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 85188, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       86243
Database pages     88733
Old database pages 32772
Modified db pages  404
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 89, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 87905, created 828, written 144339
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 88733, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       88709
Database pages     86228
Old database pages 31849
Modified db pages  416
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 74, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 85242, created 986, written 125488
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 86228, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   188416
Free buffers       89274
Database pages     85690
Old database pages 31651
Modified db pages  152
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 50, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 84945, created 745, written 121586
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 85690, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
12 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=23082, Main thread ID=47539640346368, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 41354196, updated 11172945, deleted 162, read 73718192892
510.50 inserts/s, 133.53 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1031351.20 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: I wonder if connection pooling is part of the _problem_.  I see no reason for interrogating the system for the value of `tx_isolaiton`; can you figure out what is doing that?